# How to create EditText that have another view on top of it, but the text is properly shown

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view

How to create EditText that have another view on top of it, but the text is properly shown around the another view.

I uploaded the sample view I want to create.
[image]

Imagine the line is the shown text, and the 1st-4th line (text) is shown until the bound of IMG AREA. But the 5th line is take entire space.

So, this is just not a simple use of framelayout, but i dont know how.

Comment: i think you should use relative layout to show view on another view. but i feel that you may not get exact 100% as in this pic. and also it can be vary with devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout to overlap views.[Check this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/) for a simple tutorial on FrameLayouts